# Could the Borg have origins from an awry experiment in the Delta Quadrant?

Tags: star-trek, borg

Could the Borg have been a result of a civilization in the Delta Quadrant trying to develop advanced medical nanites and the experiment went awry?

Comment: Have you actually read the duplicate target to see if this is a duplicate or not or do you just doubt it?

Comment: In Star Trek, anything is possible.